# Failed to load ApplicationContext while running AppTest.class in java spring project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-test, applicationcontext

I'm writing spring web-program. After I wrote controllers,mappers and so on I need to test them. Before this I just tried to run my BankAppApplicationTests.class that was generated automatically, method @Test void contextLoads() {} failed.
This is my test class:

```java
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application.yaml", "classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master-test.xml"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = BankAppApplication.class, properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test"})
class BankAppApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

[This is project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwGCp.png)

I have two properties.yaml files (the only difference between them is url for datasource(i created two DB - one for main app, second for testing)):

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: default

  main:
    banner-mode: off

  datasource:
    url: ${datasource.url}
    username: ${datasource.username}
    password: ${datasource.password}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Program run without problem - it creates DB, DB filled via liquibase, code works.
Test fails, and database for test does'nt filled in.

I expect my test class run without errors and database for test created and filled succesfully but it not.

```
10:59:33.497 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add PropertySource to Environment
```

---

Thanks to M. Deinum reply, i deleted @TestPropertySource from my class test, and second - i deleted from both my yaml files:
"profiles:
active: default"

After it - testslass runned successfully and created connection with test-DB.

Comment: `@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application.yaml", "classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master-test.xml"})` will not work as it doesn't load YAML nor XML files. Also having 2 files named `application.yaml` will not work as it will only load the one from `src/test/resources`. Also `${datasource.url}` doesn't really seem a valid URL. If really the only different is the url just rename the one in the test directory to `application-test.yaml` and remove all but the URL config, that way it will override the one from the main.

Comment: @M.Deinum ${datasource.url} - i use here an environment variable, it already works for my main database

Comment: It doesn't work for your test. As stated rename the file and just include it in the file. Make sure that the variable is available when running the tests as well. Using environment variables for this instead of putting them in the file isn't really helping. If you really want to override just provide the regular (or test) URL in the file and for production specify the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` parameter which will automatically override the specified one (or just leave it out and only include it in the test, that way it will fail if you forget the variable in production.).

Comment: I left version with variables for application.yaml as it works. For application-test.yaml i deleted variables and wrote:
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test

  main:
    banner-mode: off

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankappschematest
    username: root
    password: 100
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db.changelog-master-test.xml

now i get: Property 'spring.profiles.active' is invalid

Comment: As stated before -> `@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application.yaml", "classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master-test.xml"})`will not work as it doesn't load YAML nor XML files. Remove it!

Comment: already removed, i have now only
@SpringBootTest(classes = BankAppApplication.class, properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test"})